# Basic Algebra - binary to decimal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone remind of how do that.. it looks basic but I don't know
how did we get from left side to right side?

$2^{-23}  ≈ 10^{-7}$

Comment: Not that close....$2^{23}=8388608$.  I'd start with $2^{10}\sim 10^3$ which implies $2^{20}\sim 10^6$ so $2^{23}\sim 8\times 10^6$.

Comment: $2^{10}\approx 10^3$ gives a popular integer approximation to $\log_2(10)$ and $\log_{10}(2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that $2^{-23}\approx10^{-7}\iff2^{23}\approx10^{7}$.

Second, go from $2^{23}$ to $10^{7}$ as follows:

$2^{23}=$

$2^{10\cdot2+3}=$

$(2^{10})^{2}\cdot2^{3}=$

$1024^{2}\cdot8\approx$

$1000^{2}\cdot10=$

$(10^{3})^{2}\cdot10^{1}=$

$10^{3\cdot2+1}=$

$10^{7}$

Answer (score 1):

One way:

$\log_{10}2 \approx 0.3010$, so $\log_{10}2^{-23}\approx -23 \times 0.3010 = -6.923 \approx -7$.

Another way:

$2^{10}=1024 \approx 10^3$. So $2^{23}=8\times 2^{20} \approx 8\times 10^6 \approx 10^7$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{-23} ≈ 10^{-7}$$
$$\frac{1}{2^{23}} ≈ \frac{1}{10^{7}}$$
$$\frac{1}{8388608} ≈ \frac{1}{10000000}$$

$$0,00000011920928955078125 ≈ 0,0000001$$